# Dockerfile http-server options

Tags: docker

I'm running Vue in a docker container. In my Dockerfile, I'm trying to run the command:

http-server dist --proxy http://localhost:8080?"

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server",  "dist", "--proxy http://localhost:8080?"]
```

I have tried placing "--proxy http://localhost:8080?" everywhere in the CMD array.

```
"http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080?"
```

results in an error.

Any direction on how to get the --proxy option to run?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably expecting `--proxy http://localhost:8080` to be two separate parameters. It's what Bash does when parsing the same command.

```
CMD [ "http-server",  "dist", "--proxy", "http://localhost:8080?"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just when I felt like I tried everything. That was definitely the issue.